# Correct syntax for adding a filter aggregation in a Kibana visualization as a JSON input (filtering for a specific property value)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch.net

I am trying to perform the simplest filter for a specific property value, as a JSON input, in a Kibana visualization, thoroughly without success.

I can't, to my surprise, find concrete examples in doing that (have been searching for a couple of minutes now).

Say we have a document with the following structure:

```
{
    a: true,
    b: 10
}
```

How can I add a Filter aggregation for all documents with `a = true` ?

**I tried using "script", "query", "filters"** api, but all give me parse errors. My filter jsons are all valid, my problem is with the exact syntax elastic is expecting, but all examples I found out there and tried - give me parsing errors (after making the amendments to my index structure).

**Kibana's version: 6.4.3**

How is this accomplished ?

Comment: I've had the same question. There is definitely a llack of examples of how to use the json inputs *in kibana*. All the examples are for elasticsearch, but these have to be adapted for the kibana input, and it is not clear how

Comment: @geo909: definitely

Answer (score -1):

An example:

```
POST /sales/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
        "docs" : {
            "filter" : { "term": { "a": "true" } },
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) is the link to the official documentation with example.